# Cannot access my website from outside my localhost

Tags: osx-lion, firewall, webserver, nginx

I have test website on my system (MacBook Pro with Mac OSX Lion). The website is served by nginx listening on port 8000. The `listen` configuration is `listen 8000 default`, so it should be open to accept request on any ip.

I can access the server from localhost but I cannot even access it from other systems in the same LAN. I configured OSX firewall to allow incoming for nginx. In the firewall log I see no 'deny' reports, and also I see no 'allowed' reports. So, I suspect the connection is getting blocked even before reaching the firewall.

To test if my LAN is working fine, I installed nginx on another system in tha LAN. I could access that from my Mac. So, LAN is configured properly. What else could be the problem?

Comment: In addition to allowing incoming for nginx, have you opened incoming tcp port 8000? Take a look at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31376/how-can-i-open-port-8080-of-mac-os-x-lion

Answer (score 0):

Try to ping your machine from another one. Also, try your `IP:port` combination, e.g. `192.168.1.1:8000` from another one to hunt down the problem.

Comment: I do not get any response for the ping.

Comment: Then it must be firewall.

Comment: But I face this issue even after I turn it off!

Answer (score 0):

Are both computers on the same network? If not, it can be a firewall inside betwen the two computers. 
Does the computer you are trying to ping from have a firewall enabled? Can you ping google or any other computer in the same network for example from that computer?

Are you sure 192.168.1.1 is your MAC IP? (You can get this from Network Preferences or File Sharing in Sharing or using ifconfig on a terminal window)

After you get the right IP, try pingin from another computer in the same network.

Hope it helps.